# Overflow with horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I implemented a **Chosen** dropdown inside my **gridview**. The gridview is inside a box made of div's.

I want it to be able to open without being restricted by the grid itself. I am able to do it by adding `overflow-x:visible !important;` to the style of the grid.

I want the grid to have horizontal scrolling ability too. I add `overflow:auto;` to the grid.

But I can't do both. If I do the first and make the dropdown visible, grid goes over the box and scrolling doesn't work anymore. If I do the other, dropdown gets behind of the grid.

Is there a way to have both? Please feel free to use this sample below to show me. And forgive and ignore the filthiness of the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/tqpxqose/

```
<table cellspacing="0" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdInfo" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="height:50px;">
            <td>
                <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdInfo$ctl02$ddlItemHistory" id="ddlItemHistory" class="chzn-select chzn-done" style="display: none; background-color: rgb(128, 0, 128);">
                    <option value="27/10/2016 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ">27/10/2016 -Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </option>
                    <option value="14/09/2016 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ">14/09/2016 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </option>
                    <option value="29/06/2016 - ILorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ">29/06/2016 - Integration in UAT</option>
                    <option value="24/06/2016 -  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ">24/06/2016 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </option>
                    <option value="23/06/2016 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ">23/06/2016 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </option>
                    <option value="13/02/2015 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ">13/02/2015 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </option>
                    <option value="11/02/2015 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ">11/02/2015 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </option>
                </select>
                <div id="ddlItemHistory_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single chzn-container-active" style="width: 876px;" title=""><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single chzn-single-with-drop" tabindex="-1"><span>27/10/2016 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span><div><b></b></div></a>
                    <div class="chzn-drop" style="left: 0px; width: 874px; top: 24px;">
                        <div class="chzn-search">
                            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 839px;">
                        </div>
                        <ul class="chzn-results">
                            <li id="ddlItemHistory_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected" style="">27/10/2016 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                            <li id="ddlItemHistory_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style="">14/09/2016 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </li>
                            <li id="ddlItemHistory_chzn_o_2" class="active-result" style="">29/06/2016 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </li>
                            <li id="ddlItemHistory_chzn_o_3" class="active-result" style="">24/06/2016 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (</li>
                            <li id="ddlItemHistory_chzn_o_4" class="active-result" style="">23/06/2016 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </li>
                            <li id="ddlItemHistory_chzn_o_5" class="active-result" style="">13/02/2015 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                                </li>
                            <li id="ddlItemHistory_chzn_o_6" class="active-result" style="">11/02/2015 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(".chzn-select").chosen();
                            $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({
                            allow_single_deselect: true
                            });

                        </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                            $('#ddlItemHistory').css("background-color", "purple");
                            $("select").change(function() {
                            $('#ddlItemHistory').css('color', "yellow");
                            });

                        </script>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdInfo_lblDocumentsOutstanding_0">TestTestTest</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdInfo_lblDateCreated_0">20/06/2016 17:49:10</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdInfo_lblUserCreated_0">HakanErdogan</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/tqpxqose/2/

What I changed is that I removed the overflow-x from the div and applied directly to the select `position:absolute`

```
<select style="position:absolute" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdInfo$ctl02$ddlItemHistory" id="ddlItemHistory" class="chzn-select chzn-done" style="display: none; background-color: rgb(128, 0, 128);">
```